# What are reciprocal vectors ? I did not undertand the definition in this question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Two groups of vectors **a**, **b**, **c**, and **a**', **b**', **c**'
> are called of reciprocal if **a**.**a**' = **b**.**b**' = **c**.**c**'
> = 1 and whathever other mixed scalar product like **a**.**b**' = 0. Show that:
>
> - **c**' = (**a** x **b**)/Q
> - **a**' = (**b** x **c**)/Q
> - **b**' = (**c** x **a**)/Q
>
> Q = **a** . (**b** x **c**)

I understood that:

- **a** $\perp$ **b** $\perp$ **c**

and:

- **a** // **a**'
- **b** // **b**'
- **c** // **c**'

In this way, in three dimensions, we have that  **b** x **c** = **a**, so Q = 1. And it makes no sense, because this way would be **a** = **a**', **b** = **b**' and **c** = **c**'.

How to solve that ?

Comment: $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a}' = 1$ does not necessarily imply $\mathbf{a} \| \mathbf{a}'$.

Comment: There is no requirement that the vectors in a group are perpendicular. Also $|\mathbf{a}|$ can be any number

Comment: I know that my assumption is wrong. But how to show what the question is asking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to show that

1. The given formulas for $\mathbf{a}'$, $\mathbf{b}'$, $\mathbf{c}'$ satisfy the definition, and
2. Show these reciprocal vectors are unique, i.e. if $\mathbf{a}''$, $\mathbf{b}''$, $\mathbf{c}''$ are an alternate set of reciprocal vectors to $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$, then $\mathbf{a}' = \mathbf{a}''$, $\mathbf{b}' = \mathbf{b}''$, $\mathbf{c}' = \mathbf{c}''$.

The second step is important from a logical standpoint, but I have a feeling that whoever asked you the question was not really expecting you to complete it.

---

To complete the first step, recall the scalar triple product:
$$[\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}, \mathbf{r}] = (\mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{q}) \cdot \mathbf{r}.$$
We will need the following properties:

- $\displaystyle{[\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}, \mathbf{r}] = [\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}] = [\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}]}$
- If any two of $\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}, \mathbf{r}$ are the same, then $\displaystyle{[\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}, \mathbf{r}] = 0}$.

Then,
$$Q = [\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}] = [\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}, \mathbf{a}] = [\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}].$$

This means, for example,
$$\mathbf{c}' \cdot \mathbf{c} = \frac{\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}}{Q} \cdot \mathbf{c} = \frac{[\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}]}{Q} = 1,$$
and
$$\mathbf{a}' \cdot \mathbf{b} = \frac{\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c}}{Q} \cdot \mathbf{c} = \frac{[\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}, \mathbf{c}]}{Q} = 0.$$
The other $4$ calculations follow similarly.

---

To show uniqueness, we first show that $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$ form a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$. Since there are three such vectors, it suffices to show linear independence.

Suppose $d\mathbf{a} + e\mathbf{b} + f\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$. Taking the inner product of both sides with, say, $\mathbf{a}'$, we get
\begin{align*}
&d(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a}') + e(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{a}') + f(\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{a}') = \mathbf{0} \cdot \mathbf{a}' \\
\implies &d \times 1 + e \times 0 + f \times 0 = 0 \\
&\implies d = 0.
\end{align*}
Taking dot products with $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ imply $e = 0$ and $f = 0$ respectively. Thus, $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$ are linearly independent, and hence form a basis (in particular, they are spanning). One nice property is that, if a vector $\mathbf{v}$ is perpendicular to each of $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$, then it must be $\mathbf{0}$.

Suppose $\mathbf{a}''$, $\mathbf{b}''$, $\mathbf{c}''$ and $\mathbf{a}'$, $\mathbf{b}'$, $\mathbf{c}'$ are both reciprocal to $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$. Consider, for example, $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{a}' - \mathbf{a}''$. Note that it is perpendicular to $\mathbf{a}$, as
$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a}' - \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a}'' = 1 - 1 = 0,$$
and it is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}$ (or similarly $\mathbf{c}$) as
$$\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{a}' - \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{a}'' = 0 - 0 = 0.$$
Therefore, $\mathbf{a}' - \mathbf{a}'' = 0$, i.e. $\mathbf{a}' = \mathbf{a}''$. Similar arguments show $\mathbf{b}' = \mathbf{b}''$ and $\mathbf{c}' = \mathbf{c}''$ as well.

Comment: Your explanation is great !! When you say that, suposing **v** perpencicular to each vector **a**, **b** and **c** you are suposing a three dimension space. In a four-dimension space, for example, **v** it could be different of zero. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Daniel I am supposing a three-dimensional space, yes. I wouldn't know how to interpret the cross product otherwise.